# Java-reading a file, performance difference between Byte and Character Streams

Tags: java

Pretty simple question: what's the performance difference between a Byte Stream and a Character Stream?

The reason I ask is because I'm implementing level loading from a file, and initially I decided I would just use a Byte Stream for the purpose, because it's the simplest type, and  thus it should perform the best. But then I figured that it might be nice to be able to read and write the level files via a text editor instead of writing a more complex level editor (to start off with). In order for it to be legible by a text editor, I would need to use Character streams instead of Byte streams, so I'm wondering if there's really any performance difference worth mentioning between the two methods? At the moment it doesn't really matter much since level loading is infrequent, but I'd be interested to know for future reference, for instances where I might need to load levels from hard drive on the fly (large levels).

Comment: You could just make a few pairs of dummy files and measure the performance for a few thousands random file open+read operations.  The golden rule is don't optimize prematurely and certainly don't optimize anything that you can't or haven't measured.

Comment: Choose a stream/reader based on your needs, not on some imagined performance difference. In this case, the extra time required to turn bytes into characters will be overwhelmed by the time taken to read the file from disk. And the penalty for not using character streams to read character data is that you'll get corrupted files if you write with one encoding and read with another (which is likely if you plan to have people hand-edit the files).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pretty simple question: what's the performance difference between a Byte Stream and a Character Stream?

I assume you are compare Input/OutputStream with Reader/Writer streams.  If that is the case the performance is almost the same.  Unless you have a very fast drive, the bottleneck will be almost certainly the disk, in which case it doesn't matter too much what you do in Java.

> The reason I ask is because I'm implementing level loading from a file, and initially I decided I would just use a Byte Stream for the purpose, because it's the simplest type, and thus it should perform the best. But then I figured that it might be nice to be able to read and write the level files via a text editor instead of writing a more complex level editor (to start off with).

All files are actually a stream of bytes. So when you use Reader/Writer it uses an encoder to convert bytes to chars and back again.  There is nothing stopping you reading and writing bytes directly which do exactly the same thing.

> In order for it to be legible by a text editor, I would need to use Character streams instead of Byte streams,

You wouldn't, but it might make it easier.  If you only want ASCII encoding, there is no difference. If you want UTF-8 encoding with non-ASCII characters using chars is likely to be simpler.

> so I'm wondering if there's really any performance difference worth mentioning between the two methods?

I would worry about correctness first and performance second.

> I might need to load levels from hard drive on the fly (large levels).

Java can read/write text at about 90 MB/s, most hard drives and networks are not that fast.  However if you need to write GBs in second and you have fast SSD, then it might make a difference. SSDs can perform 500 MB/s or more and then I would suggest you use NIO to maximise performance.

Comment: Thanks, very informative :) I do have a fast SSD, so I might just try out the performance differences if I ever get to the point where it would actually result in some difference.

Answer (score 3):

Java has only one kind of stream: a byte stream. The class `java.io.InputStream` and `java.io.OutputStream` are defined in terms of bytes.

To convert bytes to characters, and eventually Strings, you will always be using the functionality in `java.nio.charset`. However, for your convenience, Java provides `Reader` and `Writer` methods that adapt byte streams into stream-like objects that operate on characters and Strings.

There is a CPU time cost, of course, in conversion. However, the cost is very low. If you manage to write a program that has performance dominated by this cost, you've written a very lean program indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java, so take this with a pinch of salt.

A character stream typically means each thing you read is decoded into an individual character based on the current locale, which means it's important for internationalised text data which can't be represented with just 128 or 256 different choices. The set of all possible characters is defined in the Unicode system and how you get from individual bytes to characters is defined by the encoding. More information here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

A byte stream on the other hand just reads in values from 0 to 255 and doesn't try and interpret them as characters from any particular language. As such, a byte stream should always be somewhat faster. But if you had international characters in there, they'll not display properly unless you know exactly how they were encoded.

For most purposes, human-readable data can be stored in ASCII, which only uses 7 bits of data per character and gives you 128 different characters. This will be readable by any typical text editor, and since ASCII characters are a subset of Unicode and of the UTF-8 encoding, you can read an ASCII file either as bytes or as UTF-8 characters, and the content will be unchanged.

If you ever need to store binary values for more efficient serialisation (eg. to store the number 123456789 as a 4 byte integer instead of as a 9 byte string) then you'll need to switch to a byte stream, but you also give up human-readability at this point so the issue becomes somewhat irrelevant.

It's unlikely that the size of the level will ever have much effect on your loading times - a typical hard drive can read well over a hundred megabytes per second. Code whichever way is easiest for you, and only optimise this later if your profiling shows there is a problem.

Comment: I'd just add that char and Character use 16-bit values in Java (UTF-16), see http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.lang/c/Character

Comment: For the internal representation that makes sense, but I would assume that when reading characters from a stream there would be a way of specifying a locale? It would be odd if UTF-16 was the only encoding they supported.

Comment: Yes, that's the internal representation for String and Characters, files can be encoded as ASCII, UTF-8 or whatever. What I meant was that using Characters means the read data will take twice as much memory (and there's a very small processing overhead as the data is changed to 16-bit representations) if the data in the file was originally using for example the ASCII-character set, but this probably will have almost no effect on the overall performance.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid point. What I don't understand is why I've been down-voted, as I'm not sure what is incorrect about my answer, even if it isn't as informative as the others about Java specifics.